# Get last value per day for a given user ID? Slow results, maybe index on MAX?

Tags: mysql

I'm running a set of scripts that scrape the web every 2 hours for data and adds all of that data to a table. I want to provide a graph to my users that essentially shows the latest data for each day and the progression over the month. I've got a MySQL query that worked well in the past, but is starting to become a bit sluggish due to how big the tables have become.

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT *, DATE(datetime) as nicedate FROM accounts
        WHERE ID in (

            SELECT MAX(A.id) as maxids from accounts A 
            WHERE A.userid = ?
            GROUP BY DATE(A.datetime)

        )
```

My thought process was basically to get the latest ID for each day, because that's the last entry there is for that day. It worked fine in the past but now it takes ~1s to get the results, which isn't ideal.

Is there any way I can optimise this query? Maybe some form of Index on the daily max?
Do I need to have a new table for the max for each day? This would solve some of the headaches but I'm not too fond of the idea...

Would love to know your thoughts!

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for better performance instead of a IN subquery try using a join

```
SELECT *, DATE(datetime) as nicedate 
FROM accounts
INNER JOIN  (
   SELECT DATE(A.datetime) my_date, MAX(A.id) as maxids from accounts A 
   WHERE A.userid = ?
   GROUP BY DATE(A.datetime)
) t on t.maxids = accounts.ID AND t.my_date = DATE(datetime)
```

be sure you have at least an  index  on  userid

Comment: Thanks for the reply @scaisEdge. I tried it out but I'm getting roughly the same performance +/- 5%...

Comment: have you index  on accounts ID ??? if not you should add  an index  at least on id

Comment: ... I'm an idiot, I had two indexes on ID instead of one on ID and one on Userid. I've added on on Userid and everything went much faster. With your query it's even faster still, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest an index which should help substantially, but it would require that you store the bona-fide date of each record, in addition to the full datetime.

```
ALTER TABLE accounts ADD COLUMN dt DATE;
UPDATE accounts SET dt = DATE(datetime);
```

Now add this index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON accounts (userid, dt, id);
-- omit id from the above if it be the PK and you are using InnoDB.
```

Now, the following query should run fast:

```
SELECT a1.*
FROM accounts a1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM accounts a2
              WHERE a2.userid = ? AND
                    a1.id = MAX(a2.id)
              GROUP BY a2.dt);
```

Note that the requirement to make date a separate column stems from that `DATE(datetime)` is not *sargable*, meaning that MySQL won't be able to use any index on that part of the query.

Comment: I'll give this a try. Shouldn't the index be (userid, dt, id) though?

Comment: I would create the additional column as generated column, if the mysql version supports indexing it.